# Stacking elements with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a property that allows one element in a div to stack over another element in the same div?

I know with two divs you can use `position: relative;` & `position: absolute;` to get this working, but with two elements in the same div I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: if the two elements are in a div that has position relative, they can plot over if the have position absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to *"stack"* elements on top of each other, yes you can use the `position` property.

You would use `z-index` to alter stack order; the element with the higher `z-index` would be in *front* of an element with the lower `z-index`.

You can see this here, in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24fv5s7a/1/).

```css
.el1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.el2, .el3 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 2;
}

.el3 {
    background: green;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el1">
    <div class="el2">el2</div>
    <div class="el3">el3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much.